# How do I show two (or more) values from XML file in a listbox?

Tags: xml, listbox, datasource

I am trying to show more than one value from a XML file in my listbox. I manage to show one column, but can´t seem to show two.

Here is my code :

```
    private void oppdatereListe()
    {

        if (File.Exists("gjesteInfo.xml"))
        {
            DataSet onLoad = new DataSet();
            onLoad.ReadXml("gjesteInfo.xml");
            gjesterUtenRom.DataSource = onLoad.Tables[0];
            gjesterUtenRom.DisplayMember = "FulltNavn";
        }
    }
```

I have tried :

gjesterUtenRom.DisplayMember = "FulltNavn" + "ID"; - Shows System.Data.DataRowView in the Databox.

gjesterUtenRom.DisplayMember = "FulltNavn" , "ID"; - Gives ; expected error

and I have tried both in the function like this :

gjesterUtenRom.DisplayMember = "FulltNavn"; 
gjesterUtenRom.DisplayMember = "ID"; - Shows only the last value, in this case "ID".

So how do I get the listbox to show BOTH "FulltNavn" column AND "ID" in the listbox?

Answer (score 1):

Listbox can only show one member so you have two options: make your own listbox or add a column to the input data that has these columns combined.